# Tracking of number of elements in an array iterated?

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, special-variables

Is there any way that number of elements iterated in an for loop can be traced in perl:
Like using special variables:

```
@arrayElements = (2,3,4,5,6,7,67);
foreach (@arrayElements) {
    # Do something
    # Want to know how may elements been iterated after 
    # some n number of elements processed without using another variable.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In perl5 v12 and later, you can use the `each` iterator:

```
while(my($index, $element) = each @array_elements) {
  ...;
}
```

However, the more portable solution is to iterate over the indices, and manually access the element, as shown by *ysth*.

In any case, the number of elements that were visited (including the current element) is `$index + 1`.

Comment: Thanks @amon ....each with arrays has an speciality like this ....Thats cool!!!!!

Comment: If you do use the iterator, for safety, make sure it is set to the beginning before the loop with a void-context `keys @array_elements;`

Comment: If you do use this, you should include a `use 5.012;`, or `use 5.12.0` in your program.

Answer (score 8):

Either just count as you go:

```
my $processed = 0;
foreach my $element (@array_elements) {
    ...
    ++$processed;
}
```

or iterate over the indexes instead:

```
foreach my $index (0..$#array_elements) {
    my $element = $array_elements[$index];
    ...
}
```

Comment: FYI, my downvote was a mislick in the Android browser.  Just noticed it, too late to alter.

Comment: You could also put the `++$processed;` in a [`continue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html "perldoc -f continue") block.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the number of elements in an array as

```
    my $num = @arrayElements;
    print $num;
```

OR

```
   my $num = scalar (@arrayElements);
   print $num;
```

OR

```
   my $num = $#arrayElements + 1;
   print $num;
```

And for finding number of elements iterated, we can use the below code :

```
my $count = 0;  #initially set the count to 0
foreach my $index(@arrayElements)
{
  $count++;
}
print $count;
```